# Is it possible to comment out blocks of code that contain comments?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Say I have code like this

```
some_line_of_code
some_line_of_code
/* some comment about code */
some_line_of_code
some_line_of_code
```

and i would like to comment out a whole block like this

```
/*
    some_line_of_code
    some_line_of_code
    /* some comment about code */
    some_line_of_code
    some_line_of_code
*/
```

As you can see even SO code parser will not consider last 2 lines of code comments. Is it possible to comment out blocks of code that contain comments?

edit :
To clarify, I need this to be able to comment out large sections of code to check if a function I changed can compile in a package that otherwise can't be compiled until all changes have been done.

Comment: Not sure what IDE you are using, but there are some with great shortcuts. For instance - I highlight every line no matter the comments in between and once I hit Cntrl+/  .... Bam! All lines have been commented. Like I said though, this is an IDE specific

Comment: I am so used to having such functionality in Visual studio, but i'm new to Oracle SQL Developer which im using atm. Which ide were u refering to that allows this ctrl+/?

Comment: JetBrains has the best IDE in my opinion. There are many versions for different types of work. I work with PHP mostly so I use PHPStorm which works nicely with SQL, JS, HTML. Check out products here - https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html?fromMenu

Comment: Since you focus on SQL this blog may pertain to you http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2014/06/09/0xdbe-brand-new-ide-for-dbas-and-sql-developers/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In SQL Developer, I highlight all lines of PL/SQL that I want commented and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Obviously, you would like a way to comment and uncomment multiple lines quickly. This will put `--` in front of each line you have highlighted. Do the same command to uncomment.

Answer (score 6):

you can assign a function key through Tools > Preferences > Key Configuration (Edit / Selection / Comment Lines).

Comment: Exactly what I was needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Shortcut to comment a line:
Command + Option + /
(in Mac)

Answer (score 3):

As was stated by @Acroneos, there is no way. This is common behaviour of most programming languages. Comments as well as oher tokens are recognized by lexers. And lexers work with context-free grammars. i.e. lexes usually can recognize only reqular expressions.

You can still use C/C++ approach (`#if 0`/`#endif`). See [Conditional compilation](http://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/conditional-compilation-10gr2.php). But it does not look "so nice".

```
begin
 something1;
 $if false $then
  something2;
 $endif;
endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **--**

so this code :

`some_line_of_code
some_line_of_code
-- some comment about code 
some_line_of_code
some_line_of_code`

will be :

`--some_line_of_code
--some_line_of_code
---- some comment about code 
--some_line_of_code
--some_line_of_code`

Comment: Regardless of it working or not, it is far from fast and elegant way to comment out large sections of code to check if your function can compile.

Comment: This approach work perfectly with Emacs. By executing uncomment-region on selected region, only one level comments is removed. And of course comment-region will add one level of single line comments to every selected line.

Comment: I always use VS / SublimeText, and both of these editors have this feature of adding comments, on vb it's a (quote), on C++ it's //

Comment: You tagged* your question as "oracle/plsql", what code are you trying to comment out ? isn't it a plsql ?

Answer (score 0):

No, because everything between first delimiter until the next last delimiter will be recognized as comment (=not processed by compiler). Thats how multiline-comments work: If first delimiter (/ * ) is recognized, compiler will ignore anything until the very next last delimiter ( * /) is recognized. Now as you know this, you should be able to understand, why your second / * will never be recognized as a comment-delimiter by the compiler.

However, you can mark comments with special characters or concatenations within the multiline-comment-sector to line out comments into different sections.

Answer (score 0):

in sql developer ; default shortcut is : ctrl + shift + c

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Developer,You can use the following commands...

1. For Commenting Sql Statements...
   ctl and / keys
2. For un-commenting Sql Statements...
   ctl and / keys again
3. Additionally, to format sql statement
   ctl and F7